# brownian motion on a weighted undirected graph

Tags: stochastic-processes, graph-theory

The question ["Brownian bridge interpreted as Brownian motion on the circle"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46991/brownian-bridge-interpreted-as-brownian-motion-on-the-circle) reminds me of a question along similar lines.  Say that you have a weighted undirected graph $G$, and you have constrained Brownian motion on the graph where edges have lengths equal to the reciprocal of their weights.  So for example a cycle with weight 1 (and therefore length 1) would be like the Brownian bridge.  By 'constrained' I mean that when edges meet at a vertex, the endpoints of each edge should have the same value.

So my question is how to compute the matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is the variance of the difference between values at vertices $i$ and $j$, given a matrix representation of the graph, for example the graph Laplacian or weighted adjacency matrix.

For example, if the graph is a tree, then the $(i,j)$ entry should be proportional to the sum of edge lengths along the unique path between vertices $i$ and $j$.  But when there are cycles in the graph, the variance should be lower because of the additional brownian-bridge-like constraints.

Answer (score 3):

You're basically talking about the [Gaussian Free Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_free_field) on a graph. There are many recent works on that and also on similar random embedding of graphs, e.g. [hypercube](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4636).